# CCAvenue Configured but not displayed

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 , I installed package for CCAvenue from MagentoConnect, Configured it by entering MerchantId and Key and URL. But No CCAvenue payment option is displayed on my site, Only Paypal option is displayed, when I disable Paypal, No option is displayed. If any body has any idea, please share to me. Thank You.

Comment: There could be way to many reasons for this, from a miss configuration on your part on the module, to incorrect code in module etc etc. Way to little information given to debug this. Also have you tried contacting the module developer for help?

Comment: Thank you Marius, The Problem has been resolved, The checkout configuration had some wrong configuration.

Comment: Please can you set an answer with that, and accept it - else your question will stay open-ended....

Comment: @ProxiBlue Users with < 15 rep cannot answer their own question. Ref http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank You ,
I solved the Problem by Changing the some configuration in Check out option in 
System > Configuration.